# Is Luleå's PM10 indicative of poor air quality?

Tags: atmosphere, air-pollution, air-quality, particulates

Today (17/04/2023) Luleå in Sweden has one of the lowest air quality values in the world according, to Microsoft's air quality map. Other regions with a similar value are near deserts or large urban areas. However according to [Weather underground](https://www.wunderground.com/health/se/lule%C3%A5) the same PM value in Luleå is classified as good air quality.

[It is not pollen season](https://www.wunderground.com/health/se/lule%C3%A5) or any news I could find about the poor air quality. What are other sources for high PM value that are relevent for Luleå, and is PM10 indicative of poor air quality?

Note: I have never visited Luleå so there may be conditions I am not aware of.

[image: Air Quality map of Luleå]

Answer (score 1):

[Luleå](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lule%C3%A5) has a very large steel industry. This coupled with weather conditions, such as temperature inversions would be likely factors for high readings in particulate matter air pollution.

The [steel plant](https://www.gem.wiki/SSAB_Lule%C3%A5_steel_plant) produces 2.3 Mt of steel per annum.

The site [tutiempo.net](https://en.tutiempo.net/air-quality/lulea.html) has classified the air for "today", 17 April 2023 as being very unhealthy.